# SUMO: how to add name place to show in sumo simulator

Tags: python, sumo

I get network from OpenStreetMap (OSM) and i need to show the name of place in sumo so how can i do that

[in osmEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot2ao.png)

in sumo how to show name
[in sumo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXpFb.png)

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can create arbitrary points of interest with netedit and show their ID or an arbitrary label in the sumo-gui, see https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Netedit/editModesNetwork.html#shapes

If you like editing XML by hand write an additional file with a content like this

```
<additional>
    <poi id="id" color="red" name="myName" lon="13.526713" lat="52.426404"/>
</additional>
```

and load it into sumo-gui.

Comment: This solution did not work for me, but I solved the issue by displaying the type of the POI. thank you so much Mr